# Can't be able to inject httpmodule into custom service, Angular 2 Error Can't resolve all parameters for TypeDecorator

Tags: angular, angular2-services, node-modules, angular-http

I am an angular 2 beginner and I was following a tutorial... but got stuck at this point. I am not able to move forward cause I am not able to inject HTTP service inside the custom service(message.service.ts).

I Tried to find figure it out,I found this is happening due to "CIRCULAR DEPENDENCY" but I am not able to solve this.

Edit : I tried with HttpClient also... but no luck!

Please help me with some correct line of codes so,this would make this code working again.

// message.service.ts

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Message } from './message.model';

@Injectable    <--- If i am removing this injectable code is working fine
export class MessageService {
    private messages: Message[] = [];

    constructor(private http: Http) {} <-- and I need to comment out this too.. to avoid DI.

    url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/message';

    addMessage(message: Message) {
        this.messages.push(message);
        const body = JSON.stringify(message);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        return this.http.post(this.url, body, {headers: headers})
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json())); <--- In this line catch is showing unresolved function.
    }

    getMessages() {
        return this.messages;
    }

    deleteMessage(message: Message) {
        this.messages.splice(this.messages.indexOf(message), 1);
    }
}
```

// app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MessageComponent } from "./messages/message.component";
import { MessageListComponent } from "./messages/message-list.component";
import { MessageInputComponent } from "./messages/message-input.component";
import { MessagesComponent } from "./messages/messages.component";
import { AuthenticationComponent } from "./auth/authentication.component";
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { routing } from "./app.routing";
import { LogoutComponent } from "./auth/logout.component";
import { SignupComponent } from "./auth/signup.component";
import { SigninComponent } from "./auth/signin.component";
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MessageComponent,
        MessageListComponent,
        MessageInputComponent,
        MessagesComponent,
        AuthenticationComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        LogoutComponent,
        SignupComponent,
        SigninComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        routing,
        ReactiveFormsModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

// Error Stacktrace:

```
compiler.js?7e34:485 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TypeDecorator: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js?7e34:485)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js?7e34:15700)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js?7e34:15535)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js?7e34:15515)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js?7e34:1587
```

Comment: try to mark your service with `@Injectable()`, like a method call

Comment: @IvanMladenov thank you so much, that solved my problem. :)

Comment: I have posted is as an answer, you can select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `()` to your `Injectable`

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a service into another service you need to have @Injectable() added.

In your code you've not added parenthesis after @Injectable, like this @Injectable().

Also important to note here that once you've created your custom service, you need to add it to providers array just like we have declarations and imports array. And be careful to add it to appropriate component as they're hierarchical.

As for the HTTPClient, it is available starting from angular version 4.3 or later. You don't have it for Angular 2.

Answer (score -1):

use HttpClient to make service calls instead of http